# Import error : No module named plotly.plotly

Tags: python, python-2.7, plotly

I am working on project and getting this error

> ImportError: No module named plotly.plotly

I tried:

1. pip install plotly
2. pip install --upgrade plotly

But `import plotly.plotly as py` didn't work.

Comment: there is nothing coded , i just install plotly and then "import plotly.plotly as py" didn't work

Comment: You've installed plotly somewhere where your python environment can't see it, what does `pip show plotly` show? if it's installed it will show the installed directory, where are you running python from?

Comment: this is the path "c:\pyzo2015a\lib\site-packages" and i have included this in environment variable . and i am using windows 7 and pyzo platform

Comment: Never used that but the docs state you're supposed to just `install` cmd: http://www.pyzo.org/start.html#step-3-install-scientific-packages. does `install plotly` work? Have you tried restarting your environment? Personally I'd just use anaconda as it just works

Comment: Make sure the path of the module is in your sys.path

Comment: @EdChum install plotly worked and its in my site-package folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if `pyzo` and `python` modules are stored at different location on your computer. And how they are referred.

But you can try following to give absolute path name for `plotly` while loading module and see if it works.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'c:\\pyzo2015a\\lib\\site-packages\\plotly')
import plotly.plotly as py
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem, but the current answer did not resolve my issues. If that's the case, here is an alternative (IDE dependent):

I was not having success with the "pip" stuff. I am using PyCharm, and the following simple steps took care of my problems in less than 30 seconds.

1. Settings
2. Click Project: "MyProjectHere" in left hand nav menu
3. Select Project Interpreter from the above drop down
4. Find the green 'plus' sign near the upper right edge of the window
   that comes up.
5. Type Plotly in the search bar
6. Click install.

Maybe one day I won't be a dumb monkey who doesn't know how to use a command line like all the cool kids, but for now this worked for me.

Comment: Based answer.  Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem installing plotly with pip and then import not being able to find it, but it worked when I used conda, instead.