# can't import plotly libraries (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I am having a bit of trouble getting my plotly imports to work. I am a new Python programmer.

I followed the following instructions to a 'T':

https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/

When I copied the demo code into pycharm, I got errors on the imports. So I found a guy who had the same question as me here:

[Import error : No module named plotly.plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46156123/3696204)

Following prompts in the comments, I used "pip show plotly" in my command line, and copied and pasted the path, and reformatted the import like so (again as prompted by comments and the accepted answer:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'c:\users\wesle\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages')
import plotly.plotly as py
```

Still getting the same red squigglies...

Is plotly the right library to be using for a beginner? I will be using it to plot the results of numerical methods like calculating function values using taylor series and linear algebra stuff. I don't need super fancy, just whatever is easiest to code. By the way, really digging Python coming from Java.

Comment: One thing maybe worth mentioning: the credentials file generated during set-up looked slightly different than the one presented in the tutorial. It had the API key and username right, but the "Stream IDs" array/list was empty.

Comment: If you can't make it work, you might consider to use `matplotlib`. Beginner here and I don't have any problems using this library.

Comment: @Piinthesky are you enjoying using it? The demo plots look really nice. Way better than the java libraries I was using last semester.

Comment: It is not as comfortable as a dedicated graphic program, but more flexible, allows animations and is way better than SPSS for sure (but then again, what isn't). You can beautify the output with [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html), if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not a command line expert and decided to look within my IDE for a tool to set up plotly, as I was not having success with the "pip" stuff. I am using PyCharm, and the following simple steps took care of my problems in less than 30 seconds.

1. Settings
2. Click Project: "MyProjectHere" in left hand nav menu
3. Select Project Interpreter from the above drop down
4. Find the green 'plus' sign near the upper right edge of the window
   that comes up.
5. Type Plotly in the search bar
6. Click install.

Maybe one day I won't be a dumb monkey who doesn't know how to use a command line like all the cool kids, but for now this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda Python for notebook, you have to manually install plotly in anaconda:

- Open Anaconda navigator
- Go to Environments
- Change installed to not installed
- Search packages field and type plotly as uninstalled
- Select it and click apply
- After it gets installed you'll be able to import the package in notebook.