# Why am I getting error message as "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.express" while it was working before?

Tags: python

I'm having this bizarre experience; I'm re-running a code to plot a geographical graph using Plotly and use

`import plotly.express as px`

but it gives me the error message saying that "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.express'".
I can confirm that plotly is installed, and most importantly it was working until last night.
How come its suddenly not finding the module name while it was working until last night?
Has something been changed?

Any feedback much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using python from a virtual environment? A "venv" or "conda environment" perhaps?

Comment: No, I'm not running it from virtual environment.

Comment: Do you have a script called "plotly.py" in your working environment, that you named?

Comment: Also, maybe you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46156491/10618163)

Comment: No, there is no such script, I even tried it on new notebook just to make sure no such script, still got the same message.

Comment: If nothing seems to be working, you can install [anaconda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html) and start using [conda environments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). They are one of the best solutions to these kind of errors. Also video for [Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mIB7IZFCE_k) and [Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VVCd0eSkYc).

Comment: Try `pip show plotly` on your terminal. Does it show you a version installed? Also, are you working on a Jupyter notebook? If notebook, then check with your kernel selected.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it turned out that upgrading plotly version solved the problem.
To upgrade plotly, I simply run the following codes to check the plotly version.

```py
import plotly
plotly.__version__
```

That gave me the output of version of plotly as '5.11.0'. Then I upgraded the plotly version to '5.11.0' by writing the following code:

```
pip install plotly==5.11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me with version '5.15.0'. I solved it by restarting my PC.
It's not a joke, it actually happened.